# CTE Recursion to get tree hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I need to get an ordered hierarchy of a tree, in a specific way. The table in question looks a bit like this (all ID fields are uniqueidentifiers, I've simplified the data for sake of example):

```
EstimateItemID    EstimateID    ParentEstimateItemID     ItemType
--------------    ----------    --------------------     --------
       1              A                NULL              product
       2              A                  1               product
       3              A                  2               service
       4              A                NULL              product
       5              A                  4               product
       6              A                  5               service
       7              A                  1               service
       8              A                  4               product
```

Graphical view of the tree structure (* denotes 'service'):

```
           A
       ___/ \___
      /         \
    1            4
   / \          / \
  2   7*       5   8
 /            /
3*           6*
```

Using this query, I can get the hierarchy (just pretend 'A' is a uniqueidentifier, I know it isn't in real life):

```
DECLARE @EstimateID uniqueidentifier
SELECT @EstimateID = 'A'

;WITH temp as(
    SELECT * FROM EstimateItem
    WHERE EstimateID = @EstimateID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ei.* FROM EstimateItem ei
    INNER JOIN temp x ON ei.ParentEstimateItemID = x.EstimateItemID
)

SELECT * FROM temp
```

This gives me the children of EstimateID 'A', but in the order that it appears in the table. ie:

```
EstimateItemID
--------------
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
      6
      7
      8
```

Unfortunately, what I need is an ordered hierarchy with a result set that follows the following constraints:

```
1. each branch must be grouped
2. records with ItemType 'product' and parent are the top node 
3. records with ItemType 'product' and non-NULL parent grouped after top node 
4. records with ItemType 'service' are bottom node of a branch
```

So, the order that I need the results, in this example, is:

```
EstimateItemID
--------------
      1
      2
      3
      7
      4
      5
      8
      6
```

What do I need to add to my query to accomplish this?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH items AS (
    SELECT EstimateItemID, ItemType
    , 0 AS Level
    , CAST(EstimateItemID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
    FROM EstimateItem 
    WHERE ParentEstimateItemID IS NULL AND EstimateID = @EstimateID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT i.EstimateItemID, i.ItemType
    , Level + 1
    , CAST(Path + '.' + CAST(i.EstimateItemID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255))
    FROM EstimateItem i
    INNER JOIN items itms ON itms.EstimateItemID = i.ParentEstimateItemID
)

SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY Path
```

With `Path` - rows a sorted by parents nodes

If you want sort childnodes by `ItemType` for each level, than you can play with `Level` and `SUBSTRING` of `Path`column....

Here [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b465/5) with sample of data

Comment: Brilliant. This is a few years old, but found it useful today. However, forgive for saying, I found the example provided in the original post hard for me to translate into a more common solution. So, I reposted your (great) idea using more common data, table name, and fields to make it easier for others to follow.

Comment: Is there any way to do order by on ItemType with level 0 and hierarchy should be remain as it is ?

Comment: Using the code above in SQL server 2017 (and ssms17) I get the error "Invalid column name 'level' " for the second level used (Level + 1). Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @farshad, [here is Micorsoft SQL Server 2017 Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a79e8/1) which works

Comment: Another thing to mention, if you want to go up the tree or down the tree, switch the parent/child columns in the join to the cte. cte.Child = table.Parent goes up, cte.Parent = table.Child goes down

Comment: Thank you. Let me ask further question: How could I sort paths with ids bigger than 9?
For example, now '10.2.3' comes before '5.6.7'.
One way is to pad each id with many zeros, like '000010.000002.000003'. But may be there is another solution?

Comment: @Ali, you can convert Path column into `HierarchyId` before ordering. You need slightly modify the path so it can be converted. [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1ef5f/6)

Answer (score 26):

This is an add-on to Fabio's great idea from above. Like I said in my reply to his original post. I have re-posted his idea using more common data, table name, and fields to make it easier for others to follow.

Thank you Fabio! Great name by the way.

First some data to work with:

```
CREATE TABLE tblLocations (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Code VARCHAR(1), ParentID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO tblLocations (Code, ParentID, Name) VALUES
('A', NULL, 'West'),
('A', 1, 'WA'),
('A', 2, 'Seattle'),
('A', NULL, 'East'),
('A', 4, 'NY'),
('A', 5, 'New York'),
('A', 1, 'NV'),
('A', 7, 'Las Vegas'),
('A', 2, 'Vancouver'),
('A', 4, 'FL'),
('A', 5, 'Buffalo'),
('A', 1, 'CA'),
('A', 10, 'Miami'),
('A', 12, 'Los Angeles'),
('A', 7, 'Reno'),
('A', 12, 'San Francisco'),
('A', 10, 'Orlando'),
('A', 12, 'Sacramento');
```

Now the recursive query:

```
-- Note: The 'Code' field isn't used, but you could add it to display more info.
;WITH MyCTE AS (
  SELECT ID, Name, 0 AS TreeLevel, CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS TreePath
  FROM tblLocations T1
  WHERE ParentID IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT T2.ID, T2.Name, TreeLevel + 1, CAST(TreePath + '.' + CAST(T2.ID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255)) AS TreePath
  FROM tblLocations T2
  INNER JOIN MyCTE itms ON itms.ID = T2.ParentID
)
-- Note: The 'replicate' function is not needed. Added it to give a visual of the results.
SELECT ID, Replicate('.', TreeLevel * 4)+Name 'Name', TreeLevel, TreePath
FROM  MyCTE 
ORDER BY TreePath;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to add the following to the results of your CTE...

1. BranchID = some kind of identifier that uniquely identifies the branch.  Forgive me for not being more specific, but I'm not sure what identifies a branch for your needs.  Your example shows a binary tree in which all branches flow back to the root.
2. ItemTypeID where (for example) 0 = Product and 1 = service.
3. Parent = identifies the parent.

If those exist in the output, I think you should be able to use the output from your query as either another CTE or as the FROM clause in a query.  Order by BranchID, ItemTypeID, Parent.

Comment: The root of a branch would be identified by a record with NULL ParentEstimateItemID. So, everything under '1' would be branch x, while everything under 4 would be branch y. I am not incredibly skilled with sql, and am learning CTE on the fly, so forgive me. Do your points need to be added in the first SELECT statement?