# Include records that has a null value on INNER JOIN SQL Server query over a tree table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, nested-table

I'm querying over a table that has nested references to itself, and I need to get records has a null reference on the INNER JOIN value which i'm using. In other words, the tree table records may not reach the same depth and I need to get all of them.

The query I'm using atm is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <valuesThatINeed>
FROM atable foo
   INNER JOIN treetable bar ON foo.id_bar = bar.id
   INNER JOIN treetable bar2 ON bar.id_bar = bar2.id
   INNER JOIN treetable bar3 ON bar2.id_bar = bar3.id
WHERE
   <constraints>
```

I've read that I can extend the INNER JOIN condition by adding an OR statement asking if bar.id_bar IS NULL, but I cannot reach further levels if I do that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <valuesThatINeed>
FROM atable foo
   INNER JOIN treetable bar ON foo.id_bar = bar.id 
   INNER JOIN treetable bar2 ON bar.id_bar = bar2.id OR (bar.id_bar IS NULL) 
   INNER JOIN treetable bar3 ON bar2.id_bar = bar3.id
WHERE
   <constraints>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <valuesThatINeed>
, CASE 
     WHEN barN.id IS NULL 
         THEN 'Your previous level with BarID = ' 
               + CAST(barN-1.id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
               + ' is the deepest level'
      ELSE ''
  END
FROM atable foo
   LEFT JOIN treetable bar ON foo.id_bar = bar.id 
   LEFT JOIN treetable bar2 ON bar.id_bar = bar2.id OR (bar.id_bar IS NULL) 
   LEFT JOIN treetable bar3 ON bar2.id_bar = bar3.id
   ...
   LEFT JOIN treetable barN ON barN-1.id_bar = barN.id
WHERE
   <constraints>
```

You can continue making `LEFT` joins until you reach a depth where your barN.id `IS NULL`, which will mean that you have reached the deepest level at `N-1`.

But if you're trying to make a hierarchy, then this is not the scalable way to go. Do a web-search for recursive CTEs ([here is a possible hint which you can try to adapt to your situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy)).

---

.

Comment: Making continuous LEFT JOIN s helped me to solve the problem. Thanks a lot.