# Add root node to SQL CTE Hierarchy Tree

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy, common-table-expression

I have a query working that shows my hierarchy tree based on [CTE Recursion to get tree hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy).

Results look like

```
- Category
- Category
- - SubCategory
- - - Sub SubCategory
- - SubCategory
...
```

I want to add a root node to my tree, but I'm not seeing how to do this.  How can I add the root node to this tree?

EDIT: My current query looks like this:

```
;WITH Tree as
(
    Select Parent_ID, ParentDescr, Node_ID, Node, 1 as Level, cast(Node as varchar(max)) as Path
    FROM Nodes
    WHERE ParentDescr = 'Root'

    UNION ALL

    Select  A.Parent_ID, A.ParentDescr, A.Node_ID, A.Node, Level + 1 as Level, cast(B.Path + ' | ' + A.Node as varchar(max)) as Path
    FROM Nodes A
    INNER JOIN Tree B ON A.PARENT_ID = B.Node_ID
    WHERE A.ParentDescr <> 'Root'
) 
SELECT  REPLICATE(' - ', level) + Node as Tree, Path, Node_ID, ParentDescr, PARENT_ID
from Tree
ORDER BY Path asc
```

Here is some sample data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
VALUES 
('123','Root',NULL,NULL),
('456','Category','123','Root'),
('789','SubCategory','456','Category'),
('012','Sub SubCategory','789','SubCategory'),
('345','Category','123','Root')) AS vtable 
([Class_ID],[Class],[Parent_ID],[ParentClass])
```

Results should look like:

```
Root
- Category
- - SubCategory
- - - Sub SubCategory
- Category
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have posted?   Are you getting an error?

Comment: Nothing wrong, I just want to add the root node.

Comment: Looks to me like you've got it, since the top half of the union uses `ParentDescr = 'Root'`.   So what is wrong with what you are getting?

Comment: ... It doesn't show "Root" node....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think you just need to change this:

```
WHERE ParentDescr = 'Root'
```

To this:

```
WHERE Node = 'Root'
```

And, similarly, change this:

```
WHERE A.ParentDescr <> 'Root'
```

To this:

```
WHERE A.Node <> 'Root'
```

EDIT:

Based on your sample data, my changes should have worked if you implemented them correctly.   Verify that your new query looks like this:

```
;WITH Tree as
(
    Select Parent_ID, ParentDescr, Node_ID, Node, 1 as Level, cast(Node as varchar(max)) as Path
    FROM Nodes
    WHERE Node = 'Root'

    UNION ALL

    Select  A.Parent_ID, A.ParentDescr, A.Node_ID, A.Node, Level + 1 as Level, cast(B.Path + ' | ' + A.Node as varchar(max)) as Path
    FROM Nodes A
    INNER JOIN Tree B ON A.PARENT_ID = B.Node_ID
    WHERE A.Node <> 'Root'  --this line really isn't even necessary
) 
SELECT  REPLICATE(' - ', level) + Node as Tree, Path, Node_ID, ParentDescr, PARENT_ID
from Tree
ORDER BY Path asc
```

It should work.

Comment: This gives me only the Root node.

Comment: Gonna have to see your raw data then.   Guessing at it isn't cutting it.