# Choosing right data structure for company tree

Tags: c#, .net

I have a slight problem determining the right data structure for one of my problems at work. What I have to do is create a "company structure tree". In short - someone is a boss of all bosses (so he is first (or zero) level of the tree) and then there are rest of the workers, but as you know, someone can be someone elses boss etc. The tree has to go max 5 levels deep. I don't really know how to create this, even from database point of view.

I've already tried custom ViewModels and some Dictionaries, but I feel like there's a working way for this, that doesn't include 5-level nested Dictionary or List.

If anyone would know how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a Self-Referencing Foreign Key on the Employees table

```
Employees

| ID    | Name  | ManagerID |
|-------|-------|-----------|
| 1     | Tom   | NULL      |
| 2     | Andy  | 1         |
| 3     | Heidi | 2         |
```

Where ManagerID is a Foreign Key on the ID.

Advantages:

- You are not limited to 5 levels
- You can have multiple root-entries
- This principle is appicable also to other self-referencing structures like menu-trees etc.
- Easy to extend if you need n:n connection you could go unnormalized (just semicolon-separate ManagerID's per field 1;2) or normalized with an own cross-table.

Answer (score 1):

What about this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    [Id] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(250),
    ...
    [Supervisor] INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee([Id])

)
```

Nullable supervisor means, that this is root of a tree. From `C#` perspective, this can be represented by `Composite Pattern` - object contains list of objects shared same interface (in our case exact type).

Comment: So basically i can use this in my Users table and reference a supervisor to itself, without creating another table?

Comment: Exactly. This have also advantage of having multiple reportees.

Answer (score 0):

On the database side [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy) is what you need. Also look at [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/).

And on the UI side, you can use [D3 tree](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092). Note [D3](http://d3js.org/) has got a learning curve, but its worth. Do take a [look at this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

Comment: I don't think he is asking for a concrete implementation framework but rather for the right way to do the data layer. Also, why suggest a javascript library when he is obviously just starting out with C#?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple json structure. I know you're dealing with c# but doing this in mongodb or some other nosql would be extremely fast.