# SQL Server CTE hierarchy issue

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

i have an application serve multilevel of permissions and roles

i have this HIERARCHY :

---

Country

....Region

........City

............Association

................Center

....................School

........................Class

---

this HIERARCHY i name it "EntityLevels"

```
| ID | Name        | ParentID |
|----|-------------|----------|
| 1  | Country     | Null     |
| 2  | Region      | 1        |
| 3  | City        | 2        |
| 4  | Association | 3        |
| 5  | Center      | 4        |
| 6  | School      | 5        |
| 7  | Class       | 6        |
```

---

i have also a Groups Table which means Jobs

```
| ID | Name               | EntityLevels |
|----|--------------------|--------------|
| 1  | CountryAdmins      | 1            |
| 2  | Region Supervisors | 2            |
```

---

the user table is as following

```
| ID | Name  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | User1 |
| 2  | User2 |
```

---

now i have a UserJobs Table or UserGroups

```
| ID | UserID | GroupdID | EntityID |
|----|--------|----------|----------|
| 1  | User1  | 1        | 1        |
| 2  | User2  | 2        | 2        |
| 3  | User3  | 4        | 38       |
```

---

now the problem is how i can get each user and his responsibilites depending on what it's under his level

for eaxmple :

user1 must have all the roles and permissoins to see all users under his level because he is in Group (1) and Group1 it resides on EntityLevel (1) which it's on the Country Level.

i've try to do something like that, but it's not working as Expected it's Only give me the root without any other child under that root

```
;WITH MyCTE AS (
  SELECT T1.ID, UserId, 0 AS TreeLevel, CAST(T1.ID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS TreePath FROM UserJobs T1
  inner join EntityLevel el on t1.GroupId = el.Id WHERE EL.ParentID IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT T2.ID, T2.UserId, TreeLevel + 1, CAST(TreePath + '.' + CAST(T2.ID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255)) AS TreePath
  FROM UserJobs T2
  inner join EntityLevel el on T2.GroupId = el.Id
  INNER JOIN
  MyCTE itms ON itms.ID = EL.ParentID
)

SELECT ID, TreeLevel, TreePath
FROM  MyCTE 
ORDER BY TreePath;
```

---

**Script for Schema And DATA**

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4cb2494ce472f22b7241aa5ef1ccfbbe)*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Assocation](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CityID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Assocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Center]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Center](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AssociationID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Center] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[City]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RegionID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_City] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Class]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SchoolID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Country]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Country] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EntityLevel]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityLevel](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Group]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EntityLevelID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Group] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Region]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Region](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CountryID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Region] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[School]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CenterID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Mobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserJobs]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserJobs](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserJobs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [UserID] ASC,
    [GroupID] ASC,
    [EntityID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Assocation] ([ID], [Name], [CityID]) VALUES (1, N'KH', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Assocation] ([ID], [Name], [CityID]) VALUES (2, N'mkh_ass', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Center] ([ID], [Name], [AssociationID]) VALUES (1, N'NorthCenter', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Center] ([ID], [Name], [AssociationID]) VALUES (2, N'SouthCenter', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[City] ([ID], [Name], [RegionID]) VALUES (1, N'Jeddah', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[City] ([ID], [Name], [RegionID]) VALUES (2, N'MakkahCiry', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (1, N'Class1-Ahmed', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (2, N'Class2-omar', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (3, N'class3_khaled', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (4, N'class4_fahd', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Country] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'KSA')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Country] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'UAE')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (1, N'Country', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (2, N'Region', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (3, N'City', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (4, N'Association', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (5, N'Center', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (6, N'School', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (7, N'Class', 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (1, N'SA', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (2, N'country admin', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (3, N'region admin', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (4, N'region Supervisor', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (5, N'manager', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (6, N'supervisor', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (7, N'teacher', 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Region] ([ID], [Name], [CountryID]) VALUES (1, N'Makkah', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Region] ([ID], [Name], [CountryID]) VALUES (2, N'Riyadh', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (1, N'School1', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (2, N'School2', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (3, N'School3', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (1, N'Loai', N'000000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (2, N'User1', N'1111')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (3, N'User2', N'2222')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (4, N'User3', N'3333')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (5, N'User4', N'4444')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (6, N'user5', N'5555')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (7, N'user6', N'6548')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (2, 2, 2, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (3, 3, 3, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (4, 4, 4, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (5, 5, 5, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (6, 6, 6, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (7, 7, 7, 2)
GO
```

(EDIT) : The Expected Result will be :

[image]

---

**SCRIPT AND DATA VERSION #2**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Assocation](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CityID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Assocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Center]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Center](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AssociationID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Center] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[City]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RegionID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_City] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Class]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SchoolID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Country]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Country] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EntityLevel]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityLevel](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Group]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EntityLevelID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Group] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Region]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Region](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CountryID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Region] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[School]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CenterID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Mobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserJobs]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserJobs](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserJobs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [UserID] ASC,
    [GroupID] ASC,
    [EntityID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Assocation] ([ID], [Name], [CityID]) VALUES (1, N'KH', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Assocation] ([ID], [Name], [CityID]) VALUES (2, N'mkh_ass', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Center] ([ID], [Name], [AssociationID]) VALUES (1, N'NorthCenter', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Center] ([ID], [Name], [AssociationID]) VALUES (2, N'SouthCenter', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[City] ([ID], [Name], [RegionID]) VALUES (1, N'Jeddah', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[City] ([ID], [Name], [RegionID]) VALUES (2, N'MakkahCiry', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (1, N'Class1', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (2, N'Class2', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (3, N'class3', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (4, N'class4', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Country] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'KSA')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Country] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'UAE')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (1, N'Country', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (2, N'Region', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (3, N'City', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (4, N'Association', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (5, N'Center', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (6, N'School', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (7, N'Class', 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (1, N'Country Manager', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (2, N'Region Manager', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (3, N'City Manager', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (4, N'Association Manager', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (5, N'Center Manager', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (6, N'School Manager', 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (7, N'Teacher', 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Region] ([ID], [Name], [CountryID]) VALUES (1, N'Makkah', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Region] ([ID], [Name], [CountryID]) VALUES (2, N'Riyadh', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (1, N'School1', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (2, N'School2', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (3, N'School3', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (1, N'UserA', N'000000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (2, N'UserB', N'1111')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (3, N'UserC', N'2222')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (4, N'UserD', N'3333')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (5, N'UserE', N'4444')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (6, N'UserF', N'5555')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (7, N'UserG', N'6548')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (8, N'UserH', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (9, N'UserI', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (10, N'UserJ', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (2, 2, 2, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (3, 3, 3, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (4, 4, 4, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (5, 5, 5, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (6, 6, 6, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (7, 7, 7, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (8, 8, 2, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (9, 9, 3, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (10, 10, 4, 2)
GO
```

---

any solution for that ?

Comment: one vote for all the scripts you post as sample data... it's easier to try to help you.  Well done

Comment: @etsa Thank you, if there is anything not clear yet i can clarify it to you.

Comment: Have you mispelled any table name in your SELECT WITH myCTE...?  Can you check please?

Comment: @etsa try it now

Comment: @etsa the query should take a user id parameter and brigns all the user that under the provided user in the tree

Comment: @etsa i have the code depending on this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40323306/1619490

Answer (score 5):

IMHO you must build the whole Entities tree and then use it to JOIN with the other tables.

Having a look at your desired result it is not clear to me what is the relation between Entities and Cities, Regions, Class, etc.

Obviously according to the Name of the entity, I know that 1 = Country, 2 = Region and so on, but I can't find out any field on your table schema that allow to get this information other than:

```
CASE WHEN Entity.ID = 1 (SELECT Name FROM Country WHERE ID = Entity.ID) END
     WHEN Entity.ID = 2 (SELECT Name FROM Region WHERE ID = Entity.ID) END
     WHEN Entity.ID = 3 (SELECT Name FROM City WHERE ID = Entity.ID) END
     ...
END as EntityName
```

I'd suggest you to build a UDF or SP to get the name of the Entity and use it on the next script.

> ```
> ;WITH tree AS
> (
>     SELECT e1.ID, e1.Name, e1.ParentID, [level] = 1
>     FROM   EntityLevel e1
>     WHERE  e1.ParentID = (SELECT EntityID FROM UserJobs WHERE UserID = 1)
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT     e2.ID, e2.Name, e2.ParentID, [level] = tree.[level] + 1
>     FROM       EntityLevel e2 
>     INNER JOIN tree 
>     ON         e2.ParentID = tree.ID
> )
> SELECT     EntityLevelID, UserName, GroupID, GroupName, EntityID, EntityName
> FROM       tree t
> INNER JOIN (SELECT gr.entitylevelid, 
>                    us.Name UserName, 
>                    gr.Name GroupName, 
>                    el.Name as EntityName,
>                    gr.ID as GroupID,
>                    el.ID as EntityID
>             FROM   userjobs uj
>             INNER JOIN [group] gr
>             ON     gr.id = uj.groupid
>             INNER JOIN entitylevel el
>             ON     el.id = gr.entitylevelid
>             INNER JOIN [user] us
>             ON us.id = uj.userid) t1
> ON t.ID = t1.EntityLevelID
> OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> EntityLevelID | UserName | GroupID | GroupName         | EntityID | EntityName 
> ------------: | :------- | ------: | :---------------- | -------: | :----------
>             2 | User2    |       3 | region admin      |        2 | Region     
>             2 | User3    |       4 | region Supervisor |        2 | Region     
>             4 | User4    |       5 | manager           |        4 | Association
>             5 | user5    |       6 | supervisor        |        5 | Center     
>             7 | user6    |       7 | teacher           |        7 | Class
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=feb537a6a79ec22a6dea2171f1f5fb5d)*

Comment: Thanks, but this Query Give me the data from the EntityLevel Table Perspective, whereas what i need is tree structure from the User Perspective. e.g. i need to know what is the Effect of powers for each User.
IF USER1 is one the Country level with id (EntityID = 1 which is KSA) i need the query to gives me everything under this country ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56510/discussion-between-mcnets-and-loai).

Comment: Hi, Can we open a Discussion Again ?, because the result not clear to me, and it's not like what i'm expecting.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this? (edited after comments)

```
;WITH MyCTE AS (
  SELECT T1.ID, UserId,  NULL AS PARENT_ID, T1.GroupID, G.EntityLevelID
  FROM UserJobs T1
  INNER JOIN [GROUP] G ON T1.GROUPID = G.ID
  inner join EntityLevel el on G.EntityLevelID = el.Id 
   WHERE T1.UserID = 1  /* Write here the user id you want */
  UNION ALL
  SELECT T2.ID, T2.UserId,  EL.ParentID, T2.GroupID, G.EntityLevelID
  FROM UserJobs T2
  INNER JOIN [GROUP] G ON T2.GROUPID = G.ID
  inner join EntityLevel el on G.EntityLevelID = el.Id
  INNER JOIN MyCTE itms ON EL.ParentID >= itms.ID 
)

SELECT B.*,  C.*, A.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  MyCTE) A
INNER JOIN [USER] B ON A.UserID = B.ID
INNER JOIN [Group] C ON A.GroupID = C.ID
 ;
```

Output:

```
    ID  Name    Mobile  ID  Name    EntityLevelID   ID  UserId  PARENT_ID   GroupID EntityLevelID
1   1   Loai    000000  1   SA  1   1   1   NULL    1   1
2   3   User2   2222    3   region admin    2   3   3   1   3   2
3   4   User3   3333    4   region Supervisor   2   4   4   1   4   2
4   5   User4   4444    5   manager 4   5   5   3   5   4
5   6   user5   5555    6   supervisor  5   6   6   4   6   5
6   7   user6   6548    7   teacher 7   7   7   6   7   7
```

Comment: Thanks, i need it from the User Perspective, cause i need to provide a userID and then the query should give me all the users are under that Provided UserID. (on the tree)

Comment: for example, if i provide a (userID =4) and this user is on `Center` Level, so the desired query should return all the users under that `Center`

Comment: can you see my edited query?  I have not very clear some fields of your tables (eg. EntityID in UserJobs)

Comment: EntityID in UserJobs Contains the Entity ID of (Conutry, Region, City, ... etc) which the user has the group.
(e.g. if the user in `UserJobs` table has GroupID  = 3 tha means the user has `region admin` Role and you will see that EntityLevelID is 2 which means = Region). Now in the UserJobs the user most assign to the specific region which is (EntityID) = 2 = `Riyadh`

Comment: Actually, I think you could use more appropriate names (EntityID --> RegionID)? :-)

Comment: that right if the `EntityID` only will be `RegionID`, but actually `EntityID `might be `CountryID`, `RegionID`, `CityID`, Depending on what the user group along with EntityLevelID

Comment: It seems to me that some table are not useful for your problem, so to make things clearer, they could be eliminated from question.  My last query is nearer to your aim?

Comment: what the tables you think it's not useful ? , you can eliminate them if you see that will help to solve the problem, the last query is give unexpected query actually becuase i should provide the UserID in order to return all the users that are under that user.

Comment: can you see my edited query? (you should eliminate tables not necessary from your post to make scenario clearer for who wants to help you ...  keep in mind for future questions)

Comment: Thank you, for now i think it the best answer i get, but there is a minor change to give an accurate Result more than this, (e.g.) (UserID : 5) it most give me only one row (his own row) because he is responsible for onbody and nobody unedr his tree.

Comment: same issue occurs on (userID = 4) his group is on `Region` Level bu under his Region there is nobody under his tree.

Comment: still here ?, anything that not clear to you ? the problem stll exist any solution for that ?

Comment: hi, do you have any problem understanding my issue ? , i really to solve this issue and i try to make another table relations , can you help me on this ?