# Collect all the nodes in a tree captured within a relational table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hierarchical-data

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Feature 
(
    FeatureId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ParentFeatureId INT,
    TargetObjectType VARCHAR(64)
)
```

As you can see, it defines a tree of features. I am interested to collect all the descendants found under the given nodes.

My current solution seems rather awkward to me:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#features') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #features

SELECT 
    0 FeatureId, TargetObjectType, ParentFeatureID
INTO 
    #features
FROM 
    Feature 
WHERE 
    1 = 0

INSERT INTO #features
    SELECT 
        FeatureId, TargetObjectType, ParentFeatureID
    FROM 
        Feature
    WHERE 
        TargetObjectType IN ('Root1', 'Root2')

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    INSERT INTO #features
        SELECT FeatureId, TargetObjectType, ParentFeatureID
        FROM Feature f
        WHERE ParentFeatureID IN (SELECT FeatureId FROM #features) 
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #features WHERE FeatureId = f.FeatureId)

SELECT * FROM #features
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing it? Using a recursive CTE, maybe?

The volume of data is insignificant (a few thousand records at most). All the data represents a forest with just a few levels of hierarchy, say 7 at the most.

Comment: Yes a recursive cte is probably the best option here.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy if you want help on writing the recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive CTE that'll give you child nodes for whatever FeatureId you pass in as the parameter at the top.  If you only want the children, change the `WHERE` clause in the first select statement of the cte to be `WHERE e.ParentFeatureId = @lookupFeatureId` instead of `WHERE e.FeatureId = @lookupFeatureId`

```
DECLARE @lookupFeatureId INT; SET @lookupFeatureId = 6;

WITH cte (FeatureId, ParentFeatureId, TargetObjectType, [Level])
AS
(
    SELECT e.FeatureId, e.ParentFeatureId, e.TargetObjectType, 0 AS Level
    FROM Feature AS e
    WHERE e.FeatureId = @lookupFeatureId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT e.FeatureId, e.ParentFeatureId, e.TargetObjectType, d.[Level] + 1
    FROM Feature AS e
    INNER JOIN cte AS d
    ON e.ParentFeatureId = d.FeatureId
)
SELECT FeatureId, ParentFeatureId, TargetObjectType, [Level]
FROM cte
```