# What is the best way to keep tree data structure in one recursive table

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, data-structures, tree

Here is my data structure look like a tree of nodes that I keep all of them in one recursive table:

```
Id   | Name    | ParentId  | Level
-----------------------------------
1    | Node1   | NULL      |  1
2    | Node2   | NULL      |  1
3    | Node3   | 1         |  2
4    | Node4   | 1         |  2
5    | Node5   | 3         |  3
6    | Node6   | 3         |  3
7    | Node7   | 3         |  3
8    | Node8   | 4         |  3
9    | Node9   | 6         |  4
10   | Node10  | 6         |  4
11   | Node11  | 8         |  4
12   | Node12  | 10        |  5
```

The problem that I have is retrieve children and parents of one Node is not performed very well, I tried to call the recursive function to fetch the children and parents. for example for `Node6`

```
retrieveAllChildrenof(6){} -> return 9,10,12;

retrieveAllParentsof(6){} -> return 3,1;
```

So I just thinking to add a new column to avoid recursive function, something like this:

```
Id   | Name    | ParentId  | Level  | Trace
---------------------------------------------
1    | Node1   | NULL      |  1     |  1
2    | Node2   | NULL      |  1     |  2
3    | Node3   | 1         |  2     |  1-3
4    | Node4   | 1         |  2     |  1-4
5    | Node5   | 3         |  3     |  1-3-5
6    | Node6   | 3         |  3     |  1-3-6
7    | Node7   | 3         |  3     |  1-3-7
8    | Node8   | 4         |  3     |  1-4-8
9    | Node9   | 6         |  4     |  1-3-6-9
10   | Node10  | 6         |  4     |  1-3-6-10
11   | Node11  | 8         |  4     |  1-4-8-11
12   | Node12  | 10        |  5     |  1-3-6-10-12
```

Now with trace field I could retrieve the children and parents as:

```
retrieveAllChildrenof(6){} -> 
//Trace(6) = 1-3-6; GetAllNodesThatStartWithTrace(1-3-6) => 9,10,12;

retrieveAllParentsof(6){} -> //Trace(6) = 1-3-6; GetNodesIdsIn(1-3); => 1,3;
```

I know the comma-separated or dash-separated data is hard to process but is there any better way to navigate in nodes and find children and parents, any suggestion?

**UPDATE**
Currently for recursive functions I used like this:
[CTE Recursion to get tree hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy)

Comment: Please share the code you use to retrieve the children and parents.  What is in those functions?  The schema you started with is a fairly common paradigm for tree representation in SQL.  Ensure you have set up the PK, FK relationships properly and indexed both PK and FKs

Comment: @user1443098 The functions is simple recursive call by parentId, the problem is not indexing, I'm wondering to retrieve data as fastest as possible, regardless of how we set the indexes.

Comment: but the recursive call could be a while loop or a recursive cte or cross apply which negates recursion... all these things can perform differently. the function would help.

Comment: here comes your answer;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy

Comment: When the problem is performance, the solution is usually indexing.

Comment: @scsimon I uodate the question. But as I said I am wondering to use not recursive function

Comment: Please share your CREATE TABLE statement, showing proper PK/FK relationships and indexing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model works well without using recursive queries.

Comment: Any reason not to use hierarchid functionality in sql server which is optimized for managing this?

Comment: @TomTom I will Check, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the tree changes only rarely you could do a depth first search, numbering the nodes as you come to them. The descendants of a node have consecutive numbers starting just after the number allocated to that node, and you could use a column to record each node's number and a column to record the number of its last descendant. Then retrieve all descendants of a node by looking up its number, the number of its last descendant, and retrieving all rows with numbers between these two.