# How to get event header value when event values have null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to get event values if event values are null as per using self joins?

Source table : `product`

I need to check `parentid` with child id values exist or not if exist then get header event values when values have null or empty.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product]
(
    [productid] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [parentid] [int] NULL,
    [childid] [int] NULL,
    [event] [varchar](50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', NULL, 64, N'billing')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 64, 65, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 65, 66, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event])  
VALUES (N'1', 64, 67, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 67, 68, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 67, 69, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 67, 70, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 67, 71, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', NULL, 5, N'collect')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 5, 6, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 6, 7, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 6, 8, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 5, 9, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 9, 10, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'1', 9, 11, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'2', NULL, 24, N'billing')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'2', 24, 25, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'2', NULL, 101, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'2', NULL, 102, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'2', 25, 30, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'2', 101, 70, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[product] ([productid], [parentid], [childid], [event]) 
VALUES (N'2', 102, 80, NULL)
```

Based on this data, I want output like this:

```
id | parentid | childid | event
---+----------+---------+--------
1  |  null    |  64     | billing
1  |   64     |  65     | billing
1  |   65     |  66     | NULL
1  |   64     |  67     | billing
1  |   67     |  68     | billing
1  |   67     |  69     | billing
1  |   67     |  70     | billing
1  |   67     |  71     | billing
1  |  NULL    |  05     | collect
1  |   05     |  06     | collect
1  |   06     |  07     | collect
1  |   06     |  08     | collect
1  |   05     |  09     | collect
1  |   09     |  10     | collect
1  |   09     |  11     | collect
2  |  NULL    |  24     | billing
2  |   24     |  25     | billing
2  |  NULL    | 101     | billing
2  |  NULL    | 102     | billing
2  |    25    |  32     | billing
2  |   101    |  70     | billing
2  |   102    |  80     | billing
```

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT
    prodcutid,
    ISNULL(p.parentid, c.parentid) parentid,
    ISNULL(p.childid, c.childid) childid,
    ISNULL(p.event, c.event) event 
FROM
    product p 
JOIN
    product c ON p.parentid = c.childid
              AND p.id = c.id
```

I am unable to get the expected results. Could you please tell me how to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is called CTE in SQL Server, this link will provide you with everything you need to make you query. hope it helps

[SQL SERVER CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy/18111876)