# Select query from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE store_category (
    store_id    int  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id char NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE category (
    category_id char NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id   char     NULL,
    name        char NOT NULL
)
```

| store_id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1a |
| 2 | 2b |
| 3 | 3c |

`category` table: this table has 3 levels of category. The highest level of category has `NULL` in `parent_id`:

| category_id | parent_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | NULL | a |
| 2b | 1a | b |
| 3c | 2b | c |

I want to get all related category name of store category.

Expected query result:

| store_id | category_id | lv1 | lv2 | lv3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1a | a | b | c |
| 2 | 2b | a | b | c |
| 3 | 3c | a | b | c |

I have an idea, I will get all category names that relate to each `category_id` in `category` table into temp table and then join temp table with `store_category` table. I wonder if that is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your review, I'll edit it right now

Comment: Do you only ever have 3 levels max? Never 4? If so just use 3 left joins.

Comment: Is there only one hierarchy (a/b/c) that applies to all stores? If so, it doesn't matter what `category_id` is assigned to a `store_id`, `lv1` will always be `'a'`, `lv2` `'b'` and `lv3` `'c'`.

Comment: There is only 3 level but each level has more than one value, can be `lv1` `aa`. My problem is getting all categories that relate to each store. I'm trying to combine left join 3 times to find the highest level of `category_id`. And according to that combine table I will get all `subcategories`. I forgot to mention that a store is not only reference to the same level of category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an idea, I will get all category names that relate to each `category_id` in category table into temp table and then `join` temp table with `store_category` table. I wonder if that is a good idea.

It *is* a good idea - except you don't need a temporary table - nor a loop. All you need is a Recursive (self-referential) CTE. CTEs are how you select data hierarchies and other graph structures.

However I don't think it's a good idea to `PIVOT` (or more specifically, `UNPIVOT`) your data into those `lv1`, `lv2`, and `lv3` columns - I know your business rules say there will only be 3 levels of depth, but your data-model *does* allow more than 3 levels of depth (unless you have a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` with a `UDF` that uses the same style of CTE query to restrict maximum `depth`). When you have a dimension of data that varies with a query (like this one!) then you should return them as rows and then format them for display to end-users in your application code, not directly in SQL.

As for the hierarchical query: Read this: [CTE Recursion to get tree hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy/18111876)

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @getThisCategoryId char(2) = '3c';

WITH my_cte AS (
    
    SELECT
        c.category_id,
        c.parent_id,
        c.name,
        1 AS depth
    FROM
        category AS c
    WHERE
        c.category_id = @getThisCategoryId 

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
        other_categories.category_id,
        other_categories.parent_id,
        other_categories.name,
        collected_so_far.depth + 1 AS depth
    FROM
        category AS other_categories
        INNER JOIN my_cte AS collected_so_far ON
            other_categories.category_id = collected_so_far.parent_id    
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_cte
    INNER JOIN store_category AS sc ON my_cte = category_id
ORDER BY
    sc.store_id
```