# Storing an arithmetic parse tree in SQL

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

SQL is obviously not meant for this but I'm wondering if it's possible to do this with SQL as a sort of challenge. Given an arithmetic parse tree such as:

```
7-2*3
```

Which could be represented as:

```
    -
   / \
  7   *
     / \
    2   3
```

And stored in SQL as the following (assuming `+-/*` binary operations on integers only):

```
CREATE TABLE expression_tree AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, 1, '-', NULL, NULL), -- "-" at top
    (1, 2, '7', 'L', 1), 
    (1, 3, '*', 'R', 1), 
    (1, 4, '2', 'L', 3), 
    (1, 5, '3', 'R', 3)
    AS tmp(expression_id, node_id, value, side, parent_node_id)
)

┌───────────────┬─────────┬───────┬──────┬────────────────┐
│ expression_id ┆ node_id ┆ value ┆ side ┆ parent_node_id │
╞═══════════════╪═════════╪═══════╪══════╪════════════════╡
│             1 ┆       1 ┆ -     ┆      ┆                │
│             1 ┆       2 ┆ 7     ┆ L    ┆              1 │
│             1 ┆       3 ┆ *     ┆ R    ┆              1 │
│             1 ┆       4 ┆ 2     ┆ L    ┆              3 │
│             1 ┆       5 ┆ 3     ┆ R    ┆              3 │
└───────────────┴─────────┴───────┴──────┴────────────────┘
```

Would it be possible to write a `WITH RECURSIVE` cte that could return `7-2*3` for the above? To start I would have something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE expression(node_id, node_value, expr_value) AS (
    SELECT node_id, value, value FROM expression_tree WHERE parent_node_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT et.node_id, et.value, 
        CASE WHEN side='L' 
          THEN CONCAT(value, expr_value) 
          ELSE CONCAT(expr_value, value) 
        END
        FROM expression_tree et JOIN expression e ON  et.parent_node_id=e.node_id
) 
SELECT * FROM expression

┌─────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ node_id ┆ node_value ┆ expr_value │
╞═════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│       1 ┆ -          ┆ -          │
│       2 ┆ 7          ┆ 7-         │
│       3 ┆ *          ┆ -*         │
│       4 ┆ 2          ┆ 2-*        │
│       5 ┆ 3          ┆ -*3        │
└─────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Here is the start of it: https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=fad7e1c0-985a-49c6-9f1b-fbbe9b83c5eb.

My difficulty in the above is basically that I need both node child node values at the same time otherwise, it will keep overwriting the L child when it gets the R child. How could that be fixed?

Comment: Do you specifically want it as a rCTE? Because it's probably more efficient using an indexed temp table and a `WHILE` loop.

Comment: If you have not seen it already, have a look:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy

Comment: @Charlieface yea just seeing how far I can extend a CTE. Of course a `while` loop would be 100x simpler as well...

Comment: Recursive aggregation (ie to *reduce* rather than expand the resultset) is difficult if not impossible in recursive CTEs. Another option if you are using SQL Server is a recursive scalar function.

Comment: I would do it in two steps: step #1 I would compute the correct order of processing using a recursive CTE, by assigning a numeric sequence/ordinal to each operation; step #2 I would use another CTE to follow that computes the arithmetic operations according to the sequence to get the final result.

Comment: Which DBMS? They each have their own dialect of SQL with differing syntax, especially for string manipulation.

Comment: @MatBailie any one is fine, it's more a challenge question. Postgres, MySQL, SQL Server, Snowflake, Oracle -- any of those is fine. In other words, I'm not actually using this in practice, just to see how/if it's possible.

Comment: I did this on my phone and can't seem to copy the code, so for now it's a link. I'll delete the comment and add an answer when I get to a computer tomorrow.  https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=84351547-c21d-449f-9428-248f10302ce3

Comment: @MatBailie pretty awesome, when you get to a computer want to post your answer and explain the thinking behind it (for example the delta and pos items?)

Comment: Just calculates the linear position (pos) from the binary tree. Root position is 0.5 and nodes below it are +/- 0.25 from that. Then +/- 0.125 for nodes one level deeper, and so on. Then string agg bundles them up in that order.

Comment: Using bigint instead of float to make it more clear : https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=36d1a81f-4d80-43ac-9ecb-71fec6b24716

Comment: When it becomes necessary to store hierarchical data in a RDBMS, for some reason they always immediately take an adjacency list. However, there are at least [five](https://www.databasestar.com/hierarchical-data-sql/) ways to store hierarchies (and their combinations). In addition, trees can be stored as XML or JSON - most modern RDBMS support them. Moreover, standard graphs can be stored in tables. Some RDBMS even have [special](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture?view=sql-server-ver16) features for working with them.

Comment: @MatBailie Sorry maybe I minsunderstanding, but I thought the aim of this was to get the final result, not to just to get a text representation of the parse tree. Ie the result here should be `1`

Comment: @David542 I think CharlieFace's question should be answered by you :)

Comment: Do you want to solve the equation or do you want to produce the equation with the operators and operands in desired order, as a string?

Comment: @SalmanA operators as a string.

Comment: @David542 Here you say you want the result as a string (representing the whole expression, but not evaluating it), yet below you say you want an integer?

Comment: @MatBailie I just meant operation on an integer (you can ignore that), meaning that you could rule out a (float) token such as `1.24E+2`.

Comment: @MatBailie for the sqlfiddle you posted -- https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=84351547-c21d-449f-9428-248f10302ce3 -- it returns a string in the second column, that's what I was commenting on.

Comment: If what you want is an expression solver, then a possible solution (Out of this realm) is to store the whole string and use a ShuntingYard Algorithm to solve. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive aggregation is difficult if not impossible using a recursive CTE. It is often easier and more efficient to use a temp table and loop until you have no rows left to aggregate.

If you want to keep it as a single query, then in SQL Server you can use a recursive scalar function.

This is made more complicated by the fact that the table is not properly normalized. The values and operators should be in separate columns, if not separate tables. Also `expression_id` seems unnecessary, as the root `node_id` should uniquely identify an expression.

- If the value of the node is convertible to a number then use that.
- Else take the child nodes and pivot them up into left and right...
- ... taking in each case the recursive value of the node.
- ... And use the correct operator to combine them.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.CalculateNode (@node_id bigint)
RETURNS bigint
AS BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN et.value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
        THEN
          TRY_CAST(et.value AS bigint)
        ELSE
        (
          SELECT
            CASE et.value
              WHEN '+' THEN L + R
              WHEN '-' THEN ISNULL(L, 0) - R
              WHEN '*' THEN L * R
              WHEN '/' THEN L / R
              WHEN '%' THEN L % R
            END
          FROM (
              SELECT
                MIN(CASE WHEN child.side = 'L' THEN v.value END) AS L,
                MIN(CASE WHEN child.side = 'R' THEN v.value END) AS R
              FROM expression_tree child
              CROSS APPLY (SELECT dbo.CalculateNode(child.node_id)) v(value)
              WHERE child.parent_node_id = et.node_id
          ) children
        )
      END
    FROM expression_tree et
    WHERE et.node_id = @node_id
  );
END;
```

Finally just select the parent node

```sql
SELECT et.expression_id, dbo.CalculateNode(et.node_id) AS final_value
FROM expression_tree et
WHERE et.parent_node_id IS NULL;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/xm3Ohc3t)

Comment: If this is what the OP wants, then I agree that a scalar function is the way to go. I'll await the OP to clarify before I add my answer :)

Comment: expression_id is beneficial for ensuring a parent and child both belong to the same expression (foreign key on expression & node)

Comment: @MatBailie yes but your answer is unique itself, so why not post that one with some explanation !

Comment: @charlieface -- beautiful answer! Let's see what MatBailie does and then I'll award the bounty!

Comment: If you want the actual string it's a pretty simple modification https://dbfiddle.uk/HmKWWFGo

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my other answer, it is also possible to do this using a temp table. This is again likely more efficient and easier than using a recursive CTE.

Note that the following solution is set-based where possible. The number of loops is only up to the max depth of the tree, not for each node.

First, insert all the data into a temp table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tree (
  node_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  value bigint,
  op varchar(2),
  side char(1),
  parent_node_id bigint,
  INDEX IX (parent_node_id) INCLUDE (side, value),
  CHECK (parent_node_id <> node_id)
);

INSERT #tree
SELECT
  et.node_id,
  CASE WHEN et.value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN et.value END,
  CASE WHEN et.value LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN et.value END,
  et.side,
  et.parent_node_id
FROM expression_tree et
WHERE et.expression_id = 1;
```

Then continuously loop as follows:

- Take all nodes which have parent nodes, and aggregate by parent node
- ... where there are no missing values
- ... and pivot up the left and right side.
- Join back to the table, and make the calculation based on the operator.
- Make the update, storing in variables the final result along with whether it has a parent.
- Break when nothing to update or we got the parent.

```sql
DECLARE @final bigint, @parent bigint;

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    WITH child AS (
        SELECT
          child.parent_node_id,
          MIN(CASE WHEN child.side = 'L' THEN child.value END) AS L,
          MIN(CASE WHEN child.side = 'R' THEN child.value END) AS R
        FROM #tree child
        WHERE child.parent_node_id IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY
          child.parent_node_id
        HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN child.value IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
    )
    UPDATE t
    SET @final = v.final,
        value = v.final,
        @parent = t.parent_node_id
    FROM #tree t
    JOIN child c ON c.parent_node_id = t.node_id
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT CASE t.op
              WHEN '+' THEN L + R
              WHEN '-' THEN ISNULL(L, 0) - R
              WHEN '*' THEN L * R
              WHEN '/' THEN L / R
              WHEN '%' THEN L % R
          END
    ) v(final)
    WHERE t.value IS NULL;
    
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 OR @parent IS NULL
        BREAK;
END;

SELECT @final;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/jjHM3WLm)

Comment: awesome, thanks again. Quick question, what does the hash mean for a table name? `CREATE TABLE #tree` ?

Comment: also couldn't you use two subselects if a recursive function (named `recurse` below), for example something like: `CASE val in ('+','-','/','*') then CONCAT(recurse((SELECT node_id FROM tbl WHERE side='L' and parent_node_id=node_id)), val, recurse((SELECT node_id FROM tbl WHERE side='=R' and parent_node_id=node_id)) ELSE val END`. It would make it much shorter if that way can be done.

Comment: `#` means a local temp table, `##` means global temp table. You could also use a table variable. Do you mean for the other answer? Yes you could do that but then you are doing two queries and index seeks for every operator rather than one.

Answer (score 2):

for the recursive query that you were going for in the question - I think the trick is to think inside-out, start with the leafs and traverse to the parents, concat the values on the way up and land at the top with the whole expression, eg:

```
with leafs as (
    select *, s = value from expression_tree t where not exists
        (select * from expression_tree where parent_node_id = t.node_id)

    union all

    select p.*, concat(l.s, p.value, r.s) from expression_tree p
    join leafs l on l.parent_node_id = p.node_id and l.side = 'L'
    join leafs r on r.parent_node_id = p.node_id and r.side = 'R')
```

the sql seems perfectly clear to me but none of the databases I tried this on would execute it. I tried postgres, sql server, db2, oracle, and mariadb - none of them allow the recursive part to be referenced more than once.

@MatBailie's solution in the comments is a brilliant workaround for this. I rewrote it to make it more clear (to me) but the gist is to rank the values and then use string_agg to assemble the expression in the right order:

```
with r as (
    select *, x = convert(real, 0), y = convert(real, 1)
    from expression_tree where parent_node_id is null

    union all

    select t.*, iif(t.side = 'L', x - y, x + y), y / 2
    from r join expression_tree t on t.parent_node_id = r.node_id)

select string_agg(value, '') within group (order by x) from r
```

[6+(3/3)-2*3](https://dbfiddle.uk/4wgnls1o)

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** For a solution, see my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78238561/1134080

*What comes below is more of a lengthy comment than a solution.*

---

Is it mandatory to represent the parse tree in a table with 5 rows the way you did?

If the smallest possible subtree *always* has three nodes connected by two vectors (except for the single-node edge case), we could use a different representation which only requires 2 rows.

```
Columns:
EI: expression_id      PK
SI: subtree_id         PK
LV: left_node_value    string   nullable
PI: parent_subtree_id  FK       nullable
PS: parent_side        'L'|'R'  nullable
PV: parent_node_value  string   nullable
RV: right_node_value   string   nullable

Rows:
EI │ SI │ LV  │  PI  │  PS  │  PV  │ RV
 1 │  1 │ '7' │ NULL │ NULL │  '-' │ '*'
 1 │  2 │ '2' │    1 │  'R' │ NULL │ '3'
```

**Constraints:**

1. Either PI or PV must be filled, but not both at the same time.
2. If PI is filled, PS must be filled.
3. Every combination of PI and PS (including `NULL, NULL`) must be unique for each EI.
4. If LV is null, PI, PS and RV must be null, with PV filled. This is for edge case of a single-node expression like `a`.

It would be relatively easier to build the expression whether recursively or iteratively.

**Iterative approach (very easy):**

1. Start with `SI 1`: Build expression `7 - *` (an expandable array-like data structure would be best to hold it).
2. Move to `SI 2`: Replace `*` in previous expression to get `7 - (2 * 3)`
3. Once all rows are exhausted, concatenate everything in the array-like data structure into a string.

**Recursive approach (a bit more complex):**

1. Start with `SI 1` which has `NULL, NULL` for `PI, PS`: Check if the left and right nodes are terminal or non-terminal.
2. If a non-terminal node is present, find the row that matches the node. That is, `EI, SI, side of node (L or R)` of current node matches `EI, PI, PS` of found node.

   - If node found, recurse to step 1 on the found node and repeat.
   - If no node found, return the current node's expression itself.
3. If both nodes are terminal, return their combination up the chain until we get back to `SI 1`.

**PS:** It looks like there's a lack of clarity whether you want the function to return the expression or the computed value. Your question is asking for expression, but many answers and comments are talking about computing the value. I'm assuming you want the expression, hence I'm using the strings.

Comment: Indeed that was the point I made which is that the table is denormalized anyway.

Comment: Yeah I'd rather normalize the data than play gymnastics with denormalized data.  BTW @David542: If the different representation and the approaches are acceptable and you want to see code, I could take a stab at one of them. Just let me know which one. #bounty

Answer (score 1):

See example. Recursive assembling expression formula from expression_tree table.

```
with triple as( --  recursive if PostgreSql
    select expression_id,oid
        ,concat(
            case when lv in('*','+','-','/') then concat('{',lid,'}') 
            else cast(lv as varchar) end 
            ,ov
            ,case when rv in('*','+','-','/') then concat('{',rid,'}') 
             else cast(rv as varchar) end
            )frm
    from(
        select o.expression_id,o.node_id oId,o.value oV,o.side oSide
          ,l.node_id lId,l.value lV,l.side lSide, r.node_id rId,r.value rV,r.side rSide
        from expression_tree O
        inner join expression_tree L on l.expression_id=o.expression_id
              and l.parent_node_id=o.node_id and l.side='L'
        inner join expression_tree R on r.expression_id=o.expression_id 
            and r.parent_node_id=o.node_id and r.side='R'
    )t
)
,r as(
    select 0 lvl, expression_id,oid,cast(frm as varchar)frm --,lid,rid
    from triple
    union all
    select lvl+1,r.expression_id,r.oid
        ,cast(
          replace(r.frm,concat('{',t1.oid,'}'),concat('(',t1.frm,')'))
            as varchar)frm
    from r 
    inner join triple t1 on t1.expression_id=r.expression_id 
        and r.frm like concat('%{',t1.oid,'}%')
)
select * 
from (select *,row_number()over(partition by expression_id order by lvl desc) rn from r)x
where rn=1 ;
```

For test I take 4 expressions:

1. 7-(2*3)
2. 9-(3*(4+5))
3. (13+14)*(15/16)
4. (6+(3/3)-2*3)

Query from 3 parts:

1.Take all three-nodes (triple) `<Left(l)-parent(o)-right(r)>`. Parent is operation ('+','-','*','/')

| expression_id | oid | frm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | "7-{3}" |
| 1 | 3 | "2*3" |
| 2 | 1 | "9-{3}" |
| 2 | 3 | "3*{5}" |
| 2 | 5 | "4+5" |
| 3 | 1 | "{2}*{3}" |
| 3 | 2 | "13+14" |
| 3 | 3 | "15/16" |
| 4 | 1 | "{2}-{3}" |
| 4 | 2 | "6+{7}" |
| 4 | 3 | "2*3" |
| 4 | 7 | "3/3" |

2. Recursive assembling the formula (CTE r).
   There frm - expression formula.
   We will explicitly denote the order of execution with parentheses so that we do not have to take into account the priorities of arithmetic operations.

| lvl | expression_id | oid | frm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | "7-(2*3)" |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | "9-(3*(4+5))" |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | "(13+14)*(15/16)" |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | "(6+(3/3))-(2*3)" |

For example `(13+14)*(15/16)`

```
1.1 {2}*{3} where {2}=(13+14) and {3}=(15/16)
```

Next step generate 2 rows.
You say `My difficulty in the above is basically that I need both node child node values at the same time otherwise, it will keep overwriting the L child when it gets the R child. How could that be fixed?`.
We can take any option. We take all rows.

```
2.1 (13+14)*{3} 
2.2 {2}*(15/16)
```

Next step generate also 2 rows from 2 rows of previous level. And can take any of them.

```
3.1 (13+14)*(15/16) 
3.2 (13+14)*(15/16)
```

We take all rows.

3. Take result row - any of rows with max level of recursion (row_number()...).

Recursion result (full)

| lvl | expression_id | oid | frm (formula) | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | "2*3" | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | "7-{3}" | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | "7-(2*3)" | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 3 | "3*{5}" | 6 |
| 0 | 2 | 5 | "4+5" | 4 |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | "9-{3}" | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | "3*(4+5)" | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | "9-(3*{5})" | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | "9-(3*(4+5))" | 1 |
| 0 | 3 | 3 | "15/16" | 6 |
| 0 | 3 | 2 | "13+14" | 5 |
| 0 | 3 | 1 | "{2}*{3}" | 7 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | "{2}*(15/16)" | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | "(13+14)*{3}" | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | "(13+14)*(15/16)" | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | "(13+14)*(15/16)" | 2 |
| 0 | 4 | 1 | "{2}-{3}" | 10 |
| 0 | 4 | 2 | "6+{7}" | 12 |
| 0 | 4 | 3 | "2*3" | 11 |
| 0 | 4 | 7 | "3/3" | 13 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | "{2}-(2*3)" | 8 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | "(6+{7})-{3}" | 9 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | "6+(3/3)" | 7 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | "(6+{7})-(2*3)" | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | "(6+(3/3))-{3}" | 6 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | "(6+{7})-(2*3)" | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | "(6+(3/3))-(2*3)" | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | "(6+(3/3))-(2*3)" | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | "(6+(3/3))-(2*3)" | 2 |

Tested for SQL Server and PostgreSQL

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4fWhVzPi)

Upd1. Answer corrected after comment about testing (6+(3/3)-2*3).

Comment: this fails for `(6+(3/3)-2*3)`

Comment: gordy, thank you. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution made while sticking to the original question scenario as closely as possible:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/d-KWgIhx?highlight=1) (**Note:** tested with PostgreSQL 16.)

The result is in the last column of the last row in the table given by this SQL. The way I do this is by flattening the left and right into single row, and also by using `REPLACE[node_id]` as a method of communicating from higher row down to the lower row.

[image: example result]

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE expression(left_node_id, right_node_id, left_value, right_value, expr_value) AS (
    SELECT -- parent_node_id,
           node_id as left_node_id,
           node_id as right_node_id,
           value, value, CONCAT('REPLACE[', node_id, ']')
      FROM expression_tree WHERE parent_node_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -- et.parent_node_id,
           et.left_node_id, et.right_node_id,
           et.left_value, et.right_value, 

  REPLACE( expr_value, CONCAT('REPLACE[', et.parent_node_id, ']'),

  CONCAT(CASE WHEN et.left_value IN ('+', '-', '*', '/')
          THEN CONCAT('REPLACE[', et.left_node_id, ']')
          ELSE et.left_value
         END, 

  CASE WHEN et.parent_node_id=e.left_node_id
               THEN e.left_value
               ELSE e.right_value
            END,

  CASE WHEN et.right_value IN ('+', '-', '*', '/')
          THEN CONCAT('REPLACE[', et.right_node_id, ']')
          ELSE et.right_value
         END)

  ) -- END REPLACE
  
  FROM (
          SELECT etl.expression_id, etl.parent_node_id,
            etl.node_id as left_node_id,
            etr.node_id as right_node_id,
            etl.value as left_value,
            etr.value as right_value
          FROM (SELECT * FROM expression_tree WHERE side='L') etl
          JOIN (SELECT * FROM expression_tree WHERE side='R') etr
          ON etl.expression_id = etr.expression_id
          AND etl.parent_node_id = etr.parent_node_id
        ) et JOIN expression e
               ON  et.parent_node_id=e.left_node_id
               OR  et.parent_node_id=e.right_node_id
) 
SELECT * FROM expression;
```

**Note:** You cannot add `parent_node_id` in the `UNION ALL` or the server will run out of heap space. I think it will become infinite recursion, maybe.

**Note:** This assumes that brackets (parenthesis) is not necessary to represent the parse tree. If they are necessary, some additional logic will need to be added to detect such scenario correctly and add the brackets:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S2N_AFHL?highlight=1)

[image: example result with brackets]

```sql
-- same as before

  CONCAT(
  CASE WHEN
      (CASE WHEN et.parent_node_id=e.left_node_id
          THEN e.left_value
          ELSE e.right_value
       END)
  IN ('+', '-') THEN '(' ELSE '' END,
  
  -- same three cases as before

  CASE WHEN
      (CASE WHEN et.parent_node_id=e.left_node_id
          THEN e.left_value
          ELSE e.right_value
       END)
  IN ('+', '-') THEN ')' ELSE '' END)
  ) -- END REPLACE

-- same as before
```

To avoid adding brackets at the root level, add `AND et.parent_node_id != 1` to both cases above (after `WHEN .. IN (..)` before `THEN`) then you will have `7-2*3` in this example, but you can also have `(7-2)*3` in a different parse tree where the subtraction should be done before the multiplication.

## Final

This will be the final answer, incorporating ALL of the above, and also correcting for `expression_id` not being checked in above versions:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p2MyYtrA?highlight=1)

[image: two expressions result]

The second expression has the parse tree:

```
    *
   / \
  -   3
 / \
7   2
```

## Bonus:

Just the final expression values only: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fouW5FBo?highlight=1)

[image: bonus results]

Comment: Nice. You can simplify by using grouping instead of the join https://dbfiddle.uk/B3mDrv0j?highlight=1 also better formatting

Comment: Thanks. I know I could clean this up a bit, but right now I was just hacking. It gets more and more complex. Haha. But I think I have it comprehensive now. @David542 I just updated it with the Final answer.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks. Try doing that in the final or bonus I just added. OK I think I'm really done! Hahaha 

Comment: this fails for `6+(3/3)-2*3` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V2rAMkWc)

Comment: @gordy yeah [if there are two `REPLACE`](https://dbfiddle.uk/lGlEmjJ4) like this: `(6+REPLACE[7])-REPLACE[3]` it fails because it can't replace both. I don't have a solution ri[g](https://dbfiddle.uk/dyPoylX6)ht now. Good catch though. I'll need to think about it.